# Windows git client over ssh for local repository?

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh, samba

I have a set-up where I have a remote git server, a local git/development machine running Linux, and a Windows development machine.

I generally use putty from windows to log into my local linux development machine, which is where my local git repository resides, as well as where I do my compiling, etc.

I'd like to use a (gui) git client on my windows development machine to manage this git repo, particularly for visualizing branches, etc, since my linux machine is mostly headless.

It it possible to control it using a windows git client via SSH, so that I can use windows to manage my local git repository on my linux dev machine? I don't want to have a repo on both my windows and linux dev machines, and I don't want to go through a two-stage push process.

My other option I suppose is to add my linux machine as a network drive under windows and connect that way, but it's awfully slow.

**(And if anyone has any recommendations for which windows client is good and can do this, please let me know. I'd like to use SourceTree, but I don't think it's capable of this)**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to split the use of the repository on both machines? On Windows because of graphic presentation (e.g. in SourceTree) and on Linux because of?